# flutter: RaisedButton is bigger than its SizedBox

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to place a `RaisedButton` inside of a blue circle (Container with `BoxDecoration`).

As far as I understand, a `RaisedButton` sizes itself by shrinking to the size of its `child` or a minimal reference size, whichever is bigger. But for me, the `RaisedButton` inflates itself to cover the entire screen. It does this, even though it is wrapped in a `SizedBox` with explicit `width` and `height`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Container(
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: Text(
              "Test",
            ),
            onPressed: () {}),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Here is the result:
[image: screen which is all orange]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `alignment` property.

[Align the child within the container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/alignment.html)

The right way is:

```
runApp(
  MaterialApp(
      home: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          child: RaisedButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: Text("Test",),
              onPressed: () {}),
        ),
      )
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

hello you can use the clip oval widget to get this effect. here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Container(
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Center(
          child: ClipOval(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 120.0, 
              width: 120.0, 
              child: RaisedButton(child: Text('text'), onPressed: (){},),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```